# MacOS - setting a keyboard shortcut for running an automator service using Terminal

Tags: macos, service, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, automator

Been searching through and through, but I haven't been able to find relevant information online.

As the title suggests, I have a `Automator workflow` that I saved and appears under `/Users/MY_USER/Library/Services/flow.workflow`.
The workflow is detected by the OS and appears correctly under `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services` under `General -> flow`.

What I'm trying to do is very simple: I want to set a global keyboard shortcut for the `flow` service **using the terminal**.
Doing that will allow me to quickly run that service using a global keyboard shortcut.
I get that you can manipulate keyboard shortcuts using `defaults write` but I can't figure out how to do that for services.
The closest I've managed to come up with was:

```
defaults write -g NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "flow" -string "@$~^k"
```

Unfortunately, that didn't seem to set a keyboard shortcut for the service.

Would appreciate any help.
Thanks!